# What Python 64-bit hash for file integrity checks?

Tags: python, hash, 64-bit, cross-platform, data-integrity

I need a standard, 64 bit hash, that is platform independent, to use for photo and video file integrity checks.  Python doesn't offer a 64-bit hash.  So I chose to use the first 16 chars of an MD5 hex digest for my hash.  It's a little slower than I'd like, but works.

Can I do better?

Comment: If I may ask, why the requirement that it be 64 bits?

Comment: You might be able to create a Python version of [_A strong 64-bit hash function in Java_](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/collections/strong_hash_code_implementation.shtml).

Comment: Rob, my typical photo size is about 30 MB which is my main concern. I'm concerned that CRC32 isn't good enough for 30 MB files based on a bit of research.  I know "good enough" is defined by the eye of the beholder.  But I still want the greater protection of a decent 64-bit hash.

Comment: I could use a Java-based 64-bit hash, but I've never interfaced python code with java code.  Two language run-time requirements make distribution a lot hairier.  I considered using one of the open source C implementations for a fast 64-bit hash, but abandoned that path because it didn't appear to be possible to be platform independent without creating/maintaining multiple binaries of the code.